# remounting in recovery does not work

Tags: permissions, root, recovery-mode

I am trying to enter into recovery mode with read and write permissions.

All the info I can find on doing this, says to run the following command

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

But when I run that, I get the error...

> special device remount does not exist

What is this error mean? How can I remount my filesystem in read/write mode?

Ultimately I need to edit my fstab.

Comment: I don't know about recovery mode, but it's easy to fix fstab using a live usb session.  See the answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/971347/reset-disks-package-to-automount-at-startup-using-command-line/981634#981634

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all I needed to do was go to the option in recovery mode called "fix broken packages" and this prompts you that it will mount file system in read/write.

Then I dropped down to a root terminal, and was able to edit the fstab.