# Cannot login after adding user to group

Tags: login, recovery-mode, groups

I was trying to install amdpro divers, so followed the [instructions](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) and after installing the driver run this command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME
```

After that, I'm locked out of the PC.

To resolve this, I entered as root in recovery mode and run

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433446/31464) but I get this error:

```
mount: special device remount does not exist
[Time ] Timed out waiting for devide dev-di...
[Depend] Dependency failed for /devdisk/by-...
[Depend] Dependency failed for Swap
```

So have left clueless and appreciate your help.

Comment: post the error you get.

Comment: The error is `mount: special device remount does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of threads out there on this with various solutions.  [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/985101/remounting-in-recovery-does-not-work) suggests using "fix broken packages" in recovery mode to enable r/w.  There is a comment in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254223/unable-to-mount-filesystem-as-read-write-in-recovery-mode) suggesting enabling networking helped.

Comment: running fix broken packages and then  following https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433446/31464  solved the problem. Thanks!